# Error playing music in Java program

Tags: java, audio

Ok, so today I finally decided to ask what the issue was with my Java program after various attempts to fix it. If you didn't read the title, here is my issue: I'm trying to play music in a program, but it returns an error.

So first, I have to put the most important part; the class

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

public class Runawaytrain {
    public void play() { 
        try { 
            AudioInputStream in = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("hard1.wav"));
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip(); 
            clip.open(in); 
            clip.start(); 
            Thread.sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength()); 
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Runawaytrain().play();
    }
}
```

This program I actually used as a test, since the music I was using in a game I'm co-creating wouldn't play. So when I made this program, I got the same stack trace:

```
javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input file
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1189)
    at krap2.Runawaytrain.play(Runawaytrain.java:12)
    at krap2.Runawaytrain.main(Runawaytrain.java:22)
```

The file hard1.wav is included in my project directory. For some reason, it won't play however, and keeps returning that stack trace.

But I found something pretty odd about my program; when I use music from a URL, it works. So I tried inserting a URL using the file:// protocol, but still no luck.

So anyway, to finish this off, I'll put some info that may help in answering the question:

• OS: Mac

• JVM installed: 1.8.0

• Music source: Originally an MP3 file, converted through VLC into a .wav format

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't appear that there's anything wrong with your code. I would check to make sure that the `hard1.wav` is in the correct place your project tree and that it is named correctly. Also -- if I recall, I had some issue compiling this on Mac OS X. If you compile this as a JAR on a Windows machine, it should compile fine and you can run the resulting JAR on OS X.

Comment: is `hard1.wav` actually a wav file?

Comment: @redflar3 hard1.wav is definitely a .wav file, as I've compiled it into a .wav file multiple times

Comment: @wadda_wadda I don't have a windows machine xP. Good to know my code works though

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you need to put the entire system path of the file when making the new File() (so on a Windows it would be "Users/username/.../hard1.wav" or whatever it would be on a Mac).

Comment: Oh, trust me, I've tried that .-. thanks for suggestion though